# ASP.MVC session lost when downloading file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Download page with links to files stored locally on the web server. All is well when a user opens a text file, but when they open an Office file and choose "Open" from the resulting dialog in IE or Firefox, ASP creates a new session.

My simplified controller method is:

```vb
<HttpGet()>
<AppAuthorize(Domain.Security.TransactionId.Download)>
Public Function Download(fileName As String) As ActionResult
    ' fileName example: C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyApp\SomeFile.txt
    Return New FilePathResult(fileName, "application/octet-stream")
End Function
```

Debugging shows that as soon as you click "Open" in the browser, the Global.asax Session_Start() event is triggered.

[image]

If you Save the file and then view it in IE a new session is not created. It is only a problem if you click the Open button as pictured above.

Why is this and how can I prevent it?

The core problem is that when my app sees a new session started and the user has a valid Forms Authentication cookie, it assumes IIS restarted and deletes the user's cookie. So every time a user opens a Word doc they get logged out of the app.

Comment: Are you using Session state for app authorization?  If so, you have serious security holes... session should never be used for security.

Comment: No, I'm using a custom implementation of Forms Authentication. The link between session state and "logging out" is that if I detect a new session and the user has a valid forms auth cookie, I assume IIS reset and delete their auth cookie to maintain data integrity. See http://www.netnewsgroups.net/aspnet/t4780-forms-authentication-session-expiration.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When a DOC link is clicked in Internet Explorer, it hands it off to Word.  This means that Word does the downloading, not IE.  Because of this, there is a new "browser connection" made and a new session will be created because it's not actually IE doing the downloading.

Comment: Okay, so that explains the "why"... now how can I fix it? This must be a common scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question.

I found a solution after [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19104237/1036274) pointed me in the right direction. I simply disabled SessionState for the controller by adding an attribute as follows:

```
<SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)>
Public Class AttachmentController
    ...
End Class
```

Now Office can download files but not trigger a new session. My app is no longer broken.